# How do I use `add_next_tick_callback` for a Panel-wrapped Bokeh figure?

Tags: python, bokeh, panel, holoviz

I have a Bokeh figure in a notebook (VS Code), which I would like to update when the `x_range` is changed. To enable callbacks from JS to Python, I wrap the figure in a Panel `panel`:

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
import panel as pn
pn.extension(comms='vscode')

fig = figure()
fig.circle([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])

tai = pn.widgets.input.TextAreaInput(sizing_mode='stretch_both')
panel = pn.Row(pn.pane.Bokeh(fig), tai)

def change_callback(attr, old, new):
    tai.value += f'{fig.x_range.start}, {fig.x_range.end}\n'
fig.x_range.on_change('start', change_callback)
fig.x_range.on_change('end', change_callback)

panel
```

In this example, instead of actually updating the figure, I have an additional `TextAreaInput` to log callback events. This is what it looks like:

[image]

The problem is that every change of `x_range` leads to **four** events, and the figure update might take a second. (Two events make sense because I have two callbacks, but why is every event sent twice?) I would therefore like to prevent the update from being performed four times.

Looking at the Bokeh documentation, there is a method `add_next_tick_callback`. The idea would be to add this callback whenever an event occurs, but also remove an old callback if it exists. Something like

```py
ntc = None
def tick_callback():
    tai.value += f'{fig.x_range.start}, {fig.x_range.end}\n'
def change_callback(attr, old, new):
    global ntc
    doc = curdoc()
    if ntc is not None:
        doc.remove_next_tick_callback(ntc)
    ntc = doc.add_next_tick_callback(tick_callback)
    tai.value += f'{ntc}\n'
fig.x_range.on_change('start', change_callback)
fig.x_range.on_change('end', change_callback)
```

The figure update would then be performed in `tick_callback`.

This doesn't work. `change_callback` still gets called and creates a series of `NextTickCallback` objects, but `tick_callback` never gets called.

I thought this might be due to `curdoc()` not returning the correct Bokeh document in the context of Panel. There is also `fig.document`, which however gives the same document as `curdoc()`. And there is `pn.state` which has an `add_periodic_callback` method, but not `add_next_tick_callback`.

How do I use `add_next_tick_callback` for a Panel-wrapped Bokeh figure?

Comment: Speaking plainly, I think any solution along these lines (trying to add/remove callbacks) will be incredibly brittle and subject to race conditions, unfortunately. In the past there was not a good way to trigger a single callback on "total range change" but it just occurred to me that this could be tackled in recent versions with non-property events. I have made a GH issue to propose this here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/11095 I am afraid I don't have any specific good workaround to suggest at this time.

Comment: I agree that this doesn't seem like a good approach, and thanks for creating the issue, I'll comment there.